# Give an example to show that an infinite union of affine varieties need not be an affine variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to find an example of an infinite union of affine varieties that is not an affine variety.

This is problem 15 on page 14 of Cox, Little, O'Shea; "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms"

I am having trouble starting. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Well, points are closed subsets, so take any infinite set that is not closed.